# Check if DataContext is Inherited via code

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I want to check if a DataContext value for a UserControl is **inherited** from parent element or if was directly set on the current UserControl (**local value**), via C# code.

I can find this information by using **visual studio wpf visualizer tool**, but I can't figure out how to do this via code.

I have attached a screenshot with the information that I want (yellow highlighted).
[image]

Comment: Question is unslcear. Could you please give a example of where a usercontrol is *not* inheriting FrameworkElement and is getting the DataContext property from it? | Doing that sounds like trying to make a Windows Form, without inheriting from the Form class.

Comment: As any other dependency property, DataContext can have multiple sources, i.e. local value, value from Style or Animation, default value etc. In addition it can get its value by property value inheritance. Question: find out where the value comes from. See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DependencyPropertyHelper:

```
var helper = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(
    control,
    FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty);

Debug.WriteLine(helper.BaseValueSource);
```

The type of `BaseValueSource` is the following enum (from [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/DependencyPropertyHelper.cs,4e185f83306d389d)):

```
public enum BaseValueSource
{
    /// <summary> The source is not known by the Framework. </summary>
    Unknown                 = BaseValueSourceInternal.Unknown,
    /// <summary> Default value, as defined by property metadata. </summary>
    Default                 = BaseValueSourceInternal.Default,
    /// <summary> Inherited from an ancestor. </summary>
    Inherited               = BaseValueSourceInternal.Inherited,
    /// <summary> Default Style for the current theme. </summary>
    DefaultStyle            = BaseValueSourceInternal.ThemeStyle,
    /// <summary> Trigger in the default Style for the current theme. </summary>
    DefaultStyleTrigger     = BaseValueSourceInternal.ThemeStyleTrigger,
    /// <summary> Style setter. </summary>
    Style                   = BaseValueSourceInternal.Style,
    /// <summary> Trigger in the Template. </summary>
    TemplateTrigger         = BaseValueSourceInternal.TemplateTrigger,
    /// <summary> Trigger in the Style. </summary>
    StyleTrigger            = BaseValueSourceInternal.StyleTrigger,
    /// <summary> Implicit Style reference. </summary>
    ImplicitStyleReference  = BaseValueSourceInternal.ImplicitReference,
    /// <summary> Template that created the element. </summary>
    ParentTemplate          = BaseValueSourceInternal.ParentTemplate,
    /// <summary> Trigger in the Template that created the element. </summary>
    ParentTemplateTrigger   = BaseValueSourceInternal.ParentTemplateTrigger,
    /// <summary> Local value. </summary>
    Local                   = BaseValueSourceInternal.Local,
}
```